# Navigation links go to wrong slides

Tags: table-of-contents

I desperately need help with this problem I have no idea where it comes from... I have a presentation with a structure similar to the MWE provided below. The problem is the links in the upper margin navigation and in the outline slide do not go to the correct slide. I really hope you could assist me on this, cause I have no idea what the problem might be. I work on Ubuntu 12.10 with Texmaker 3.4-1 and Beamer 3.10-2... Many thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme[compress]{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
TITLE
\end{frame}


\section*{General aim}
\begin{frame}
AIM
\end{frame}


\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}[shrink]
%\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Background}
\subsection{Cell diversity}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Cancer}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Oncogenes and tumor suppressor genes}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Cancer-causing germline-mutated genes}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Example case}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Question and goal}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}





\section{Methods \& Results I}
\subsection{Flowchart}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Identification of genes}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Gene expression per tissue}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Classification}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\end{frame}





\section{Methods \& Results II}
\subsection{GO/KEGG enrichment}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\subsection{Prediction}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}





\section{Methods \& Results III}
\subsection{Networks}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}





\section{Conclussions}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}






\end{document}
```

Comment: I ran it on my system and I just had one problem: there is a `{` on the second line of your code. Taking it away, I had no problem compiling and then with the links. I also found some warnings with the fonts, but I don't think it has anything to do with your problem. Hoever, please don't forget to run your code several times (some 3, just to be sure) and then check again if the links are OK. Some results: Windows Vista + TeXnicCenter + Adobe Reader: OK |  Windows Vista + TeXnicCenter + SumatraPDF: Problems with the links

Comment: The links in the top line point to the next subsection.

Comment: yes egreg, that's exactly what I see! why can this be happening??

Comment: After doing some trials, your code works as expected for me (this was also checked for some other user), so I'll delete my "answer".

Comment: So I have updated Tex Live to 2013 following the steps here http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
But the problem still persists in Texmaker, and when opening the resulting pdf with Okular.

Comment: However, using impressive, the links work properly... guess it is a problem with Texmaker and Okular???

Comment: This looks very much like https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/238/tableofcontents-links-to-the-next-slide to me. I've not really worked out why it happens, I'm afraid.

Comment: It sounds like you have the same problem as me. I may have a solution for you here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130783/13780